# Laravel 5.6.9 - layout not displaying consistently

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm stuck on this issue:  I am creating a series of pages based on the same master layout.  The master layout includes all references to css/js.  The first page (home page) extends the master layout and defines the "content" section (the main part of the page).  This works fine.  I created a second page that is the same as the home page except it defines different content for the "content" section.  When this page is displayed it appears that the CSS is ignored.  If I inspect elements in Chrome I can see no references to CSS files.  However, if I view source the HTML looks correct and includes the same header as my working home page.  Additionally, if I save this source in a simple HTML file and access directly in chrome it displays perfectly!

My 2 pages appear identical (except of course for the body content)

I am fairly new to Laravel and have been through all relevant Laracasts, but I am stumped by this and would welcome any suggestions!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: posting some code may help you getting answers. It is possible to misspelled some class name or hierarchy in css

Comment: Is the css sheet reffered to relatively or aboslute? because if the second page has a diff url the css might not load correctly if relatively inserted.

Comment: Thanks RTB for the pointer.  The route to the pages was different (I didn't realise that media urls were relative to the route url - I thought they were relative to public!).